# Create and Update a Single Table from SQL Backend with Multiple Tables, Using Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Good Morning All,

I'm having problem pulling the data I need from a SQL Backend and keeping it up to date.

I've got two tables, that hold the data at need. At one Point they were split due to a software update we received. First Table **dbo_PT_NC** Second Table **dbo_PT_Task**

Primary key of **PT_NC** is the "**NCR**" Field, The Task Table has its own Unique ID, But the **PT_Task.TaskTypeID** field is linked to the "**NCR**" field

```
SELECT dbo_PT_Task.TaskTypeID, 
dbo_PT_NC.NCR, 
dbo_PT_NC.NCR_Date, 
dbo_PT_NC.NC_type, 
dbo_PT_NC.Customer, 
dbo_PT_NC.Material, 
dbo_PT_NC.Rev, 
dbo_PT_NC.Qty_rejected, 
dbo_PT_Task.TaskType, 
dbo_PT_Task.Notes AS dbo_PT_Task_Notes, 
dbo_PT_NC.Origin, 
dbo_PT_NC.Origin_ref, 
dbo_PT_NC.Origin_cause, 
dbo_PT_NC.Origin_category
FROM dbo_PT_NC INNER JOIN dbo_PT_Task ON dbo_PT_NC.[NCR] = dbo_PT_Task.[TaskTypeID]
WHERE (((dbo_PT_NC.NCR_Date)>=#1/1/2016#) AND ((dbo_PT_Task.TaskSubType)="Origination"))
ORDER BY dbo_PT_NC.NCR_Date, dbo_PT_NC.Customer;
```

After I have this data pulled and put into a Snapshot (I do not want the Live Data to be accessible by the front end users) I'll be adding columns for a Weak Point Management System we are implementing, Fields Such as:

**Scrap Code** (lookup field to another table i've built inside excel)

**Containment**, **Root Cause**, **Plan**, **Do**, **Check**, and **Act**, all of which Should most likely be Memo Fields (As characters may break 255)

**Date Completed** A date the process was complete

This table (The data i've snapshotted and the new fields added) will need to be updated with New or Changed Records from the SQL Backend i've previously connected to.

**UPDATE**
Big thanks to Andre.. Got it working, Sample code below (i've added more update fields since)

```
UPDATE tblWeakPointMaster, dbo_PT_NC INNER JOIN dbo_PT_Task ON dbo_PT_NC.NCR = dbo_PT_Task.TaskTypeID 
SET tblWeakPointMaster.Qty_rejected = [dbo_PT_NC].[Qty_rejected], 
tblWeakPointMaster.dbo_PT_Task_Notes = [dbo_PT_Task].[Notes], 
tblWeakPointMaster.Material = [dbo_PT_NC].[Material], 
tblWeakPointMaster.Rev = [dbo_PT_NC].[Rev], 
tblWeakPointMaster.NC_type = [dbo_PT_NC].[NC_type]
WHERE (((tblWeakPointMaster.NCR)=dbo_PT_NC.NCR) And ((tblWeakPointMaster.TaskID)=dbo_PT_Task.TaskID));
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? This sounds more like a project summary of what you are doing but what is the problem you are having?

Comment: It is a follow-up question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865551/ms-access-update-query-error-cant-update-memo-field-that-is-actual-text-field , without this context I agree it isn't clear what the question is.

Comment: Cleared comment as Andre answered while typing, Yes.. My apologies again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a 1:n relation between `PT_NC` and `PT_Task`?

Then you should include **both** primary keys in the import SELECT.

Either use them as composite primary key in the Access tables instead of the new `KEY` column. Or if that is impractical because other tables are linking to `tblWeakPointMaster`, you can also keep that primary key.

But in any case, these two columns form the JOIN between `tblWeakPointMaster` and `tblWeakPointUpdates`.

All other columns can be used to update `tblWeakPointMaster` from `tblWeakPointUpdates` (assuming they can be edited in the original database).

Edit: if you don't use them as composite primary key, you need to create an unique index on the combination, or the JOIN will not be updateable, I think.

Comment: So i'll add the primary key from the second table PT_Task, Which appears to be a 16 character string of Hexadecimal characters).. In the Update Query, I will then Join on them, and "SET" all other fields after that?

Comment: @JamesLongfield: Is that a GUID column in Sql Server? Yikes. But if this is the identifier (primary key), then you'll have to use it.

Comment: I have No Idea, This isn't my Forte by any means, I deal with Excel Workbooks mostly doing quality documents, Im at best a backyard programmer.. I Built a simple access database for tracking a quality process and Suddenly.. All these projects come out the woodwork, which are WAYYY over my level.. After i get this running, i get to Link Qlikview to it for "pretty pictures"..

Comment: THANK YOU ANDRE.. With a little struggle i managed to get it working, I'll update the Top to include the final code sample ill be using..